# use counter outside ngfor

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, ngfor

I am trying to count number of row in my table using it ouside ngFor directive as the following code illustrate

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">IP</th>
      <th scope="col">Session_ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor='let obj of methodResponse; let theIndex = index;'>
      <th scope="row"> {{theIndex + 1}}</th>
      <td>{{obj.name}}</td>
      <td>{{obj.sourceIp}}</td>
      <td>{{obj.sessionId}}</td>
    </tr>
  <!-- I want to use the final value of theIndex value here -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

how can I count each row and use it outside the ngFor, I have tried to call a function inside ngFor but it didn't work for me, any help ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `length` property of the array to display how many elements are in the table.

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">IP</th>
      <th scope="col">Session_ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor='let obj of methodResponse; let theIndex = index;'>
      <td scope="row"> {{theIndex + 1}}</td>
      <td>{{obj.name}}</td>
      <td>{{obj.sourceIp}}</td>
      <td>{{obj.sessionId}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{methodResponse.length}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

// final value of theIndex
you can achieve it using the below code

Last value: {{methodResponse.length - 1}}